# create more than one map(collection) using for loop

Tags: java, collections

How do I create more than one map(collection) using for loop(or dynamic) in java..?

```
List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{

   Map<Integer, Map> temp.get(i) = new HashMap<Integer, Map>();
}
```

Consider temp has the values "one","two"... "ten"

Please help..

Comment: What language is this? Maybe Java?

Comment: `temp` cannot have values `"one","two"... "ten"` because it's `List<Integer>`. Do you mean `1, 2, ..., 10`?

Comment: -1 for asking a question without learning a language.

Comment: Map of what type key and value ? can you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array of 10 maps for you:

```
List<Map> temp = new ArrayList<Map>();

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{

   temp.add(new HashMap<Integer, Map>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand you. Is this what you are looking for?

```
List<Map<Integer, Map> temp = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, Map>>();

for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
   Map<Integer, Map> map = new HashMap<Integer, Map>();
   temp.add(map);
}

//Get the maps as you please here, from the tmp list
```